# How to stop the auto completion when using the login template of Blaze

Tags: html, meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-accounts

I'm using Meteor to build my project and I use the loginButtons template of Blaze for the login area. However, the browser keeps autocompleting the input boxes. How can I turn this off?

Comment: aria-autocomplete="none"; does this help?

Answer (score 0):

Add `autocomplete="off"` to the form or input elements